# Android setting manual focus by touching

Tags: android, android-camera

I am going to set the my Android App by opening the camera and enable manual focus by touching the point in to camera. The camera can refocus to the point where I have pointed on to the screen. Would you please tell me the methodology or which component should I start with to modify ?

Below is my code:

```
public void takePhoto(File photoFile, String workerName, int width, int height, int quality) {
    if (getAutoFocusStatus()){
        camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
    }

this.photoFile = photoFile;
this.workerName = workerName;
this.imageOutputWidth = width;
this.imageOutputHeight = height;
}

public void takePhoto(File photoFile, int width, int height, int quality) {
takePhoto(photoFile, null, width, height, quality);
}
```

Comment: I believe what you want is called _assisted_ focus. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_focus , Manual Focus is impossible: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2042/can-i-manually-focus-the-camera-on-my-android-phone (as of a few years ago)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Though this answer does not show how to focus in on a single area, it is definitely useful in showing how exactly to focus the camera to begin with.

Here is what i have done. This works on my device (Droid DNA by HTC), built in Android Studio

In both `OnSurfaceChanged()` and `OnSurfaceCreated()`, I have the following code: 
(`mCamera` is my private `Camera` object)

```
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        p.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

        mCamera.setParameters(p);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.autoFocus(null);
```

In the constructor, you must place

```
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

This will allow you to receive focus events. As for capturing them...

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Log.d("down", "focusing now");

        mCamera.autoFocus(null); 
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: IMO this answer doesn't solve the question, it just sets autofocus(null). It doesn't focus camera in the point selected

Comment: Youre right. On top of that, this camera API is now depricated as of API 21 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: This worked for me in KitKat, It may not work with the new camera API if you have lollipop

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using setFocusAreas() to set the focusarea where user has touched ?

Answer (score 0):

> The key here is to call camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallBack) and after
>   we focused method autofocusCallback.onAutoFocus(boolean success,
>   Camera camera) is called – call the camera.takePicture
>   (Camera.ShutterCallback shutter, Camera.PictureCallback raw,
>   Camera.PictureCallback jpeg)

See more: http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/how-to-use-autofocus-in-android/

or

> In surface changed and before preview, you can use the auto-focus
>   setting which will set the focal distance automatically, then start
>   the preview, and then auto-focus on whatever is displayed...

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

// Set camera properties first
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);

camera.startPreview();

camera.autoFocus(null);

}
```

credit: [where to put autofocus in the class android camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058122/where-to-put-autofocus-in-the-class-android-camera?rq=1)

Comment: So if I add the event arg for touching the screen and then call the AutoFocus Again and that resolves my problem?