# In Android, what is really the use for focusing of the weight area parameter?

Tags: android, focus, android-camera

In Android API 14, was introduced the possibility to focus with the camera into a specific area.
The API specifices that a weight can be supplied, but after reading several times the description, I still can't figure it out how to use it and which value to set, or under which factors to deside the weight value to use, could anyone please explain me better how to use this parameter when it comes to focusing? Thanks

[Quote from the SDK help](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Area.html#weight)

> Each Area consists of a rectangle specifying its bounds, and **a weight that determines its importance**. The bounds are relative to the camera's current field of view. The coordinates are mapped so that (-1000, -1000) is always the top-left corner of the current field of view, and (1000, 1000) is always the bottom-right corner of the current field of view. Setting Areas with bounds outside that range is not allowed. Areas with zero or negative width or height are not allowed.
>   **The weight must range from 1 to 1000, and represents a weight for every pixel in the area. This means that a large metering area with the same weight as a smaller area will have more effect in the metering result**. Metering areas can overlap and the driver will add the weights in the overlap region.

Comment: Does it determine the depth of field? My best answer is to experiment. Try it out with different weight values and see if you can notice a difference in the image.

Comment: This is why my confusion, I tried 1, 500, 1000, etc, and I can't really see any difference at all, so with the possible chance that it could be my phone the problem of why I can't see any difference, I am seeking for an answer of what this parameter does it really do.

Comment: What phone are you using? And what size rectangle?

Comment: SGIII, I tried several sizes of the focus spot, even a full screen rect

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't think I have any other ideas :( Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
public void setMeteringAndFocusArea (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Camera camera){
    Camera.Parameters camParam = camera.getParameters();

    if (cameraParameters.getMaxNumMeteringAreas() > 0){ 
        List<Camera.Area> areas = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
        Rect areaRect = new Rect(x1, x2, y1, y2);   
        areas.add(new Camera.Area(areaRect, 1000));
        camParam.setMeteringAreas(areas); //You can use only Focus Areas if you don't care for metering.
        camParam.setFocusAreas(areas);

        camera.setParameters(camParam);
    }

}
```

And don't forget to use

> camera.autoFocus();

before taking a picture, otherwise the setFocusAreas() won't have any effect.
See [this link](http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/how-to-use-autofocus-in-android/), posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851154/android-setting-manual-focus-by-touching) for a nice implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I am looking for a plain english explanation of the real meaning of the weight factor. Thansk